# How to disable app rotation in react-native ios without xcode?

Tags: ios, react-native

I know that is possible to disable the rotation using XCode, but I do not have access to some Mac in the moment, then I wonder if there is a way to do that using VSCode, and not XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this without xcode, you just have to update the key **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations** in your projects **Info.plist** file. Although you won't be able to test it without xcode.

You can search for the key **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations** in your projects **Info.plist** file and update the values as below. If you don't see any such key then simply create a new key and values as below:-

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

This would set the orientation on ios enabled as Portrait, Landscape Right and Landscape Left. If you only want it to Portrait just paste the code below:-

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply change the orientation property in your `App.json`

`"orientation": "portrait"`
or
`"orientation": "landscape"`